# CORS Preflight request to CloudFront with S3 origin does not succeed

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront, http-status-code-403

I am facing an issue with CORS when trying to make a request from my React application to CloudFront with S3 as the origin. I have gone through several similar posts but none of them have solved the issue.

When the browser makes a request to a CloudFront domain, the CORS preflight request (OPTIONS) receives a 403 Forbidden. The request has the following headers:

```
OPTIONS /data.json HTTP/2
Host: <domain>.cloudfront.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:102.0) Gecko Firefox/102.0
Accept: */*
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Referer: https://<my website domain>
Origin: <my website domain>
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

The relevant response headers are as follows:

```
HTTP/2 403 Forbidden
server: CloudFront
content-type: text/html
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-frame-options: DENY
referrer-policy: same-origin
x-content-type-options: nosniff
strict-transport-security: max-age=47304000; includeSubDomains
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-methods: GET
vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
access-control-allow-headers: *
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

I tried configuring CORS in the CloudFront distribution as follows:

```
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: All origins
- Access-Control-Allow-Header: All headers
- Access-Control-Allow-Methods: All methods
- Access-Control-Expose-Headers: None
```

I also made the CORS rule in the origin S3 bucket accept all headers/methods:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
        ]
    }
]
```

With the above configuration, I still get the same issue which I am confused why as I have kept the CORS rules very open. Could someone please help me resolve this?

Comment: You have a typo in `Access-Control-Allow-Header` (missing "s" at the end) in your Cloudfront config; as a result, the preflight response doesn't contain that header.

Comment: It's actually `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` (type in the question). I don't manually type this header but CloudFront already has this pre-filled in a form

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you're getting a 403, it might not be CORS that's the cause, but your [bucket policy](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-website-cloudfront-error-403/).

As per Amazon, verify if your bucket policies/permissions are correct. If that doesn't solve your issue, I would also suggest reviewing how CORS headers are set up (some information on that can be found [here](https://www.boxuk.com/insight/enabling-cross-domain-access-in-cloudfront/#:%7E:text=Step%201%3A%20enable%20CORS%20on,Click%20it.)

Comment: The bucket policy seems fine to me. It gives the Cloudfront OAI permissions to get and list objects from the buckets. Is there anything else I need to add?